# MQTT Plain text

Tags: javascript, node.js, mqtt

I am new to MQTT and I read something out there, and I can get all function but I get the payload only in numbers and not in plain text, sorry but if the question is something stupid but recently I'm starting in MQTT.

[image: Example]

Help pls

Comment: that's a buffer, which by default dumps the hex. use `val.toString()` to see it in text mode.

Comment: @dandavis, please change your comment to an answer so that others benefit.

Answer (score 0):

What you are printing is a String buffer. You need to print value.toString() to see the actual message.